# MongoDB convert timezone for Loganalyzer

Tags: mongodb, rsyslog, log-analysis

I have installed rsyslog-8.26.0, loganalyzer-4.1.5 and MongoDB 3.4.4 on CentOS7. 
MongoDB stores all dates and times in UTC and I can see data on Loganalyzer also UTC.

any idea to change this for local timezone?

either change MongoDB default timezone or convert timezone on Loganalyzer when output display?

Comment: use mongo schema method like tableschema.pre('save', function (next) {
}

Comment: I don't know anything about Loganalyzer, but you'd definitely want to do it there when output for display. Leave it as UTC in MongoDB.

Comment: anyone knows how to change it on Loganalyzer when output display ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use mongo schema method like below  or set default timezone at server side**

```
 tableschema.pre('save', function (next) {

 //You can store timezone according to input and use that for conversion 
 var timezone=this.timezone;
 this.date=date // converted date here using timezone
 next();
}
```

**Best is convert timezone on Loganalyzer when output display , it will support multiple timezone according to client machine**

Comment: I said  mongo schema method 'like' , not mongoose schema exactly @JohnnyHK

Comment: anyone knows how to change it on Loganalyzer when output display ?

Answer (score 0):

I found timezone line is commented on php.ini

```
;date.timezone =
```

php info says 
**Default timezone UTC**

php.ini timezone changed like below

```
date.timezone = "Australia/Melbourne"
```

and restart HTTPD

now I can see all logs with my time zone